# Is every request header necessary when construct a request for a site through python?

Tags: javascript, python, http, request, header

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Vpj.png)

I want to construct a request header to visit a site, and I obtain some header information, now the question is whether or not it is necessary to put every header information in my request header?

Comment: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the site that you are making a request to.

*A request header is an HTTP header that can be used in an HTTP request to provide information about the request context, so that the server can tailor the response.*

Some sites block `requests` specific headers and so you cannot access it. In that case you add browser specific headers to tell the site that this request is from a browser.